# Insert multiple rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a temptable in my query which could have certain records like

```
Id Name
34 one
35 two
65 five
```

Now for each row in temp table, I want to insert a new row in history table

So the history table now would have 3 new records

```
Id   created date   updatedby
34    createdDate
35    createdDate
65    createdDate
```

Comment: what is the value of updateby?

Comment: updated by will remain same and a parameter in query will hold that value.except updated by I also have some other columns but that will remain constants and will pick from parameters supplied to query. only id needs to be picked up from temp table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can insert using select.

Something like this:

```
insert into history (id, created_date, updatedBy)
select id, getdate(), 'add person here??'
from #temptable;
```

The above require the updatedBy to be supplied in the select query.

If you want current user, you could use `SUSER_NAME()`

Comment: will it generate new row in history automatically for each row in temp table?

Comment: Yes. It will insert one row for each row in temptable.